# [Framework7 Vuejs]Binding asyn data to template with v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, html-framework-7

I want to display total views for each id (1, 2, 3) by call api use axios like this:

```
<f7-block>
<f7-col 
  :key="index" 
  v-for="(items, index) in list">
  Total views: {{countView(items.id)}}
</f7-col>
```

```
export default {
  data(){
    list: [];
    // list = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
  },
  methods(){
    async countView(id){
      let url = 'xxx';
      let filter = {
        where: {
          quizId: id
        }
      }
      try{
        let res = await axios.get(url, filter);
        return res.data.countViews;
      } catch(error) {

      }

    }
  }
}
```

How to use vue async data to display number of views instead **{}** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way, which is creating a custom component for each item. Then calling `countView` inside each custom component:

**TotalView.vue**

```
<template>
  <span v-if="count !== null">
   {{ count }}
  </span>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'TotalView'
  props: ['itemId'],
  data: () => ({
    count: null
  }),
  created() {
    this.countView(this.itemId)
  },
  methods: {
    async countView(id){
      let url = 'xxx';
      let filter = {
        where: {
          quizId: id
        }
      }
      try{
        let res = await axios.get(url, filter);
        this.count = res.data.countViews
      } catch(error) {

      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

and use that in your component:

```
<f7-block>
<f7-col 
  :key="index" 
  v-for="(items, index) in list">
  Total views: <total-view :itemId="items.id" />
</f7-col>
```